# Custom directive to populate cascading drop down

Tags: angularjs

I want to populate the select dropdown from database. Right now the data is coming from scope array.

html:

```
<div ng-controller="DropDownController">
    Country: 
    <select id="country" class="input-sm" name ="country" ng-model="states" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries" drop-down required>
        <option value=''>Select</option>
    </select>

    States: <select id="state" class="input-sm" name="state" ng-disabled="!states" ng-model="cities" ng-options="state for (state,city) in states" required>
        <option value=''>Select</option></select>

    City: <select id="city" class="input-sm" name="city" ng-disabled="!cities || !states" ng-model="city" required>
        <option value=''>Select</option> 
        <option ng-repeat="city in cities" value='{{city}}'>{{city}}</option></select>        
</div>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('DropDown', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            $http.get('DropDown.do').success(function (data) {
                if (data) {
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I am not sure above directive is the right way of approach for my requirement. The servlet or url is not being called when I click on the drop down option. How do I achieve the same? I am still a beginner in angular.

Comment: i am little bit confused from your question, do you want populate dropdown list with values from DB , or do you want to call servlet url when you click on any option?

Comment: I want to populate drop down list from database

Answer (score 1):

[Directives in Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) are used when you want to more easily interact with the DOM, ajax calls have no business there. You should rather use a service or a factory to process the asynchronous request and then simply return the result in the controller for further manipulations. A [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) will also be needed since we are dealing with *asynchronous* jobs.

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('countryFactory', function($http) {
    var getCountries = function() {
        return $http.get('ajax.php').success(function(data) {
            return data;
        })
    }
    return { getCountries: getCountries }
})

app.controller('DropDownController', function($scope, countryFactory) {
    var ajaxPromise = countryFactory.getCountries();

    // Promises are executed once $http is done with the asynchronous job
    ajaxPromise.then(function(result) {
        $scope.countries = result.data;
    })
})
```

The server side (ajax.php) is simply returning an array, here you should replace it with whatever information from the database you are needed

```
<?php

echo json_encode(array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'USA'),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Australia'),
));
```

Instead of using a directive, for `select` and respectively `option` elements we can use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) so the view would look like this:

```
<div ng-controller="DropDownController">
    <select ng-options="country.name for country in countries track by country.id" ng-model="selected">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

check this snippet you had error in directive declaration its camel case , so it should be dropDown not DropDown!

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('dropDown', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          //replace with your call
             //$http.get('DropDown.do').success(function (data) {
               //// if (data) {
                  //scope.countries = data;
                //}
            //});
           scope.countries =
            {
                'USA':
                    {
                        'Alabama': ['Montgomery', 'Birmingham'],
                        'California': ['Sacramento', 'Fremont'],
                        'Illinois': ['Springfield', 'Chicago']
                    },
                'Australia':
                    {
                        'New South Wales': ['Sydney'],
                        'Victoria': ['Melbourne']
                    }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  Selected country : {{states}}
  <select id="country" class="input-sm" name="country" ng-model="states" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries" drop-down required>
    <option value=''>Select Country</option>
  </select>

</body>
```

Comment: That is code which I have provided. I want to get the data from database.

Comment: i cant provide ajax call in snippet, i just commented it out, its not same, you had typo in directive name , DropDown , it should be dropDown, its whty it has not been called.

Comment: But I never mentioned I had a problem using array from scope. Its already working fine