# Problems populating a select list with angular js and php

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to populate a select list with data from my db (php & mysql). I am working with AngularJs and Angular Material. So for i am not able to show the data from the db in the list

db situation:

- tblProjectType -> name of table
- 2 rows:

  - id_ProjectType
  - project_type

Any help or pointers would be great.

This is my html code:

```
<form ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <div layout="row">
        <md-select-label>Project type</md-select-label>

        <md-select ng-model="project_type" name="project_type" placeholder="Choose a project type" id="containerProjectType">
          <md-option ng-repeat="projecttype in projecttypes" value="{{projecttype.id_ProjectType}}">{{projecttype.project_type}}</md-option>
        </md-select>

      </div>
</form>
```

The code of my app.js is:

```
    var app = angular.module("DragDrop", ['ngMaterial']);
    app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog, $http) {

    $scope.projectTypeInfo = [];

    var getProjectTypeFunction = function(succesFn, errorFn)
    {
        $http.get('db.php?action=get_ProjectType_info')// call to the server
        .succesFn(function(data){
            succesFn(data); //call the function passed into getProjectTypeFunction with the data from the server
            console.log('Retrieved data from server');
        })
        .error(errorFn || function() {
            console.log("Error in retrieving data from server");
        })

    }

    this.reloadProjectTypeList = function() 
    {
         getProjectTypeFunction(       
          /* success function */ 
          function(data) { 
              //debugger; 
              $scope.projectTypeInfo = data; 
              //digest recycle
              //if (!$scope.$$phase) { $scope.$apply(); }
          }, 
          /* error function */ 
          function() 
          { 
              alert("Server load failed"); 
          }) 
    };
```

My php code is:

```
<?php 
include('config.php');

//echo ('test' . $_GET['action']);
switch($_GET['action'])  {
    case 'get_ProjectType_info' :
        get_ProjectType_info(); 
        break;

}

/**  Function to data from tblProjectType **/
function get_ProjectType_info(){
    $qry = mysql_query('SELECT * from tblProjectType');

    echo("test");
    //echo(qry);

    $data = array();
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        $data[] = array(
                    "id_ProjectType"    => $rows['id_ProjectType'],
                    "project_type"      => $rows['project_type']
                    );
    }

    print_r(json_encode($data));
    return json_encode($data);
}

?>
```

Comment: I think you should ask a specific question, or any question.  I don't see a question mark.

Comment: are you successfully getting data back?

Comment: @Ronnie, no it won't even console.log to see if i am connect to the db

Comment: so to call your PHP, it looks like `reloadProjectTypeList ` needs to be called which invokes `getProjectTypeFunction `. I don't see it getting called anywhere.  I see some redundancy here. You may want to rethink how you are calling the PHP file.

Comment: another thing, in your PHP you have `console.log("test");` that is not a PHP function, that is a JS function

Comment: @Ronnie, you right. i am not really sure how to make connection from my angular with php (still new at this). This is like the second time a did this ... thats why the code in my app.js is all over the place. any thoughts on how to best proceed

Comment: @GY22 ```get_ProjectType_info``` is simply returning data and you are doing nothing further more. You have to ```echo``` out whatever has been returned from the function so it can be proceeded to AngularJS

Comment: ya @Avalanche is right, nothing is actually being echoed. `print_r` will output <pre> tags I believe which will not be valid JSON at that point

Comment: @GY22 There was a question similar to this one just few days ago. You may want to take a peek for new ideas http://stackoverflow.com/a/31099736/1125161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for starters lets clean up your JS. We can reduce what you have to this:

```
var app = angular.module("DragDrop", ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog, $http)
{
  $scope.projectTypeInfo = [];

  $scope.getProjectTypeFunction = function()
  {
    $http.get('db.php?action=get_ProjectType_info')
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config)
      {
        $scope.projectTypeInfo = data;
        console.log('Retrieved data from server');
        console.log(data);
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
      {
        console.log("Error in retrieving data from server");
        console.log(data,status);
      });
  };

  $scope.getProjectTypeFunction(); //-- call the function that invokes $http.get()
};
```

In PHP your function needs to echo the data via `echo json_encode($data);`, not return it (as stated by @Avalanche).

Now, your console should output something, but you need to remove `console.log("test");` from your PHP as that will surely cause an error.

**edit**

Currently your repeat states:

```
<md-option ng-repeat="projecttype in projecttypes" value="{{projecttype.id_ProjectType}}">{{projecttype.project_type}}</md-option>
```

We have stored your data in `$scope.projectTypeInfo` therefore it needs to be modified to:

```
<md-option ng-repeat="projecttype in projectTypeInfo" ng-value="projecttype.id_ProjectType">{{projecttype.project_type}}</md-option>
```

Comment: ok i am getting an output not in my console log. (deleted the console.log in php) and i commented the return of the son_encode. but i got an error now in my console -> http://gyazo.com/c9d88469877e038789675836cf16555d.

Comment: sorry, that is a typo, `succes` should be `success`

Comment: is the list populating now?

Comment: remove `echo("test");` from your php

Comment: removed it but still nothing. it probably nothing but worth mentioning that the form is in a popup box (md-dialg -> angular material)

Comment: you need to fix your HTML. I'll modify my post

Comment: also, I am not familiar with angular-materials but it looks like `value` should be `ng-value` edited to remove `{{}}` from ng-value. Looking more at the docs, it looks like it could work with value and ng-value

Comment: there is a change -> http://gyazo.com/8c6321336a98ff7249442bfa2e3d12fb. i had to do in the ng-repeat tracy by $index or i was getting an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82129/discussion-between-ronnie-and-gy22).